# I can calculate the min or max of a row or column and I can calculate the mean of a column, but I can't calculate the mean of a row. Why not?

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a simple 2x2 data frame, I can calculate the min or max of a row or column and I can calculate the mean of a column, but I can't calculate the mean of a row. Why not?

```
> dat <- data.frame( A=c(1,2),B=c(3,4))
> dat
  A B
1 1 3
2 2 4
> min(dat[1,])
[1] 1
> max(dat[1,])
[1] 3
> mean(dat[,1])
[1] 1.5
> mean(dat[1,])
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(dat[1, ]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: `mean(unlist(dat[1,]))` OR `rowMeans(dat[1,])`

Comment: This is simply because of the way R return the results while you do a row level vs column level operation. you can run "mean(t(dat[1,]))" , if your requirement is to have mean function. Usually rowMeans are meant for such operations.

Comment: `apply(dat[1, ], 1, min)`, `apply(dat[1, ], 1, max)`, `apply(dat[1, ], 1, mean)`.

Answer (score 5):

`max` and `min` accept multiple vectors as parameters,
and calculate the maximum/minimum in all of them.

`mean` is more limited, it takes a single argument of a supported type.
For example vector is a supported type.

For more details see `?max` and `?mean`, especially the **Usage**, **Arguments**, and **Details** sections.

The type of `dat` is `data.frame`.
And so is the type of `dat[1,]`,
because a row of a data frame is also a data frame,
with a single value in each of its columns.

When you pass a data frame to `max`,
it operates on the columns (vectors) of the data frame,
returning the maximum value of all of them.

When you pass a data frame to `mean`,
it gives you an error because data frame is not one of the supported types.

You can use `unlist` to get a vector from a data frame.
It does that practically by concatenating all the vectors of the data frame.
For example `unlist(dat)` will return the vector `1 2 3 4`.
`dat[1,]` is the first row of `dat`,
which has vectors `1` and `3`,
so `unlist(dat[1,])` will return the vector `1 2`.
You can call `mean` on that.

Answer (score 3):

If all of your columns are numeric, you can just use `rowMeans(dat)`. To compactly select the numeric ones, you could do (for example) `rowMeans(iris[, 1:4])`.

If you don't want to have to worry about identifying which columns are numeric, you could also use `sapply()` to generate logical column indices for subsetting:

```
rowMeans(iris[, sapply(iris, is.numeric)])
```

Note also that `rowMeans()` has an `na.rm` parameter, which you can set to `TRUE` if you think your data might have missing values.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to lefft's amswer, you don't need to know the numeric columns, and can use `Filter` to find them.

```
rowMeans(Filter(is.numeric,dat),na.rm=T)
```

will do the trick.  That being said, if you know the columns, `is.numeric` and `Filter` in conjuction are a lot slower than simply listing out the columns.

*EDIT*

Sorry, I wished I could have left that as a comment to the previous answer, as I thought it was useful clarification, but had no other way of posting.  To give it a little more info about the overhead, I ran a micro benchmark on the ways of grabbing the numeric columns:

```
library(microbenchmark)
df.mb<-data.frame(
  c(runif(10000)),c(runif(10000)),c(runif(10000)),
  c(rep("A",10000)),c(rep("A",10000)),c(rep("A",10000)),
  c(rep("A",10000)),c(rep("A",10000)),c(rep("A",10000)))
names(df.mb)<-c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i")


function1<-function(x) {rowMeans(Filter(is.numeric,x))}
function2<-function(x) {rowMeans(x[,1:3])}
function3<-function(x) {rowMeans(x[,c("a","b","c")])}
function4<-function(x) {rowMeans(x[ ,sapply(x,is.numeric)])}

microbenchmark(
  function1(df.mb),
  function2(df.mb),
  function3(df.mb),
  function4(df.mb)
)

Unit: microseconds
         expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 function1(df.mb) 351.148 372.4810 768.2310 464.0005 492.5875 16216.321   100   a
 function2(df.mb) 317.441 338.5605 667.6871 429.6545 442.0270 15281.921   100   a
 function3(df.mb) 317.867 340.4810 581.0908 421.1205 439.0410  8965.121   100   a
 function4(df.mb) 363.521 385.2810 735.4673 461.6535 519.2545 15701.334   100   a
```

As long as you know the columns by name and number, you are faster, but barring that either Filter or sapply will help.

Comment: Not having enough rep is not a good reason to post a comment as an answer... Please either include more details to make it a full answer, or remove this "comment" and come back again when you have enough rep.

Comment: @useR I find it useful as its own answer

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms If lefft's answer was not there, then yes, this could be considered an answer, but currently it looks more like a comment to lefft's answer than it's own separate answer. Even the author himself said that it should be a comment..